# The Google Analytics API does not find PagePath

Tags: java, google-analytics-api

I am trying to report google analytics data to a database using JAVA, but certain addresses are returning null even if the URL exists.

Example: / catalog / companyX / US / en ----- it finds.

/catalog/companyX/US/en/research ------ he can't find it.

I tried using the filter "ga: pagePath=@/research" and it always returns null. What will be the problem? Because on google analytics site he finds these URLs.

```
public GetReportsResponse getReport(AnalyticsReporting service) throws IOException {
    // Create the DateRange object.
    DateRange dateRange = new DateRange();
    dateRange.setStartDate("2019-10-06");
    dateRange.setEndDate("2019-10-06");

    // Create the Metrics object.
    Metric timeOnPage = new Metric().setExpression("ga:timeOnPage");
    Metric totalEvents = new Metric().setExpression("ga:totalEvents");
    Metric avgSessionDuration = new Metric().setExpression("ga:avgSessionDuration");
    Metric hits = new Metric().setExpression("ga:hits");

    // Create the Dimensions object.
    Dimension browser = new Dimension().setName("ga:browser");
    Dimension device = new Dimension().setName("ga:deviceCategory");
    Dimension country = new Dimension().setName("ga:country");
    Dimension page = new Dimension().setName("ga:pagePath");
    Dimension eventCategory = new Dimension().setName("ga:eventCategory");
    Dimension eventAction = new Dimension().setName("ga:eventAction");
    Dimension eventLabel = new Dimension().setName("ga:eventLabel");
    Dimension date = new Dimension().setName("ga:date");
    Dimension pageTitle = new Dimension().setName("ga:pageTitle");

    ReportRequest request6 = new ReportRequest().setViewId(VIEW_ID).setDateRanges(Arrays.asList(dateRange))
            .setPageSize(100000)
            .setMetrics(Arrays.asList(totalEvents, hits, avgSessionDuration, timeOnPage))
            .setDimensions(Arrays.asList(date, country, page, browser, device, eventCategory, eventAction,
                    eventLabel, pageTitle));

    ArrayList<ReportRequest> requests = new ArrayList<ReportRequest>();
    requests.add(request6);


    // Create the GetReportsRequest object.
    GetReportsRequest getReport = new GetReportsRequest().setReportRequests(requests);
    // Call the batchGet method.
    GetReportsResponse response = service.reports().batchGet(getReport).execute();

    // Return the response.
    return response;
}

public void printResponse(GetReportsResponse response) {

    for (Report report : response.getReports()) {
        ColumnHeader header = report.getColumnHeader();

        List<String> dimensionHeaders = header.getDimensions();
        List<MetricHeaderEntry> metricHeaders = header.getMetricHeader().getMetricHeaderEntries();
        List<ReportRow> rows = report.getData().getRows();

        if (rows == null) {
            System.out.println("No data found for " + VIEW_ID);
            return;
        }

        for (ReportRow row : rows) {
            TableGA tableGA = new TableGA();
            Acessos acessos = new Acessos();
            List<String> dimensions = row.getDimensions();
            List<DateRangeValues> metrics = row.getMetrics();
            if (row.getDimensions() != null) {

                for (int i = 0; i < dimensionHeaders.size() && i < dimensions.size(); i++) {
                    switch (dimensionHeaders.get(i)) {
                    case "ga:browser":
                        tableGA.setBrowser(dimensions.get(i));

                        break;
                    case "ga:deviceCategory":
                        tableGA.setDevice(dimensions.get(i));

                        break;
                    case "ga:country":
                        tableGA.setCountry(dimensions.get(i));

                        break;
                    case "ga:pagePath":
                        tableGA.setPage(dimensions.get(i));

                        break;
                    case "ga:eventCategory":
                        tableGA.setEventCategory(dimensions.get(i));

                        break;
                    case "ga:eventAction":
                        tableGA.setEventAction(dimensions.get(i));

                        break;
                    case "ga:eventLabel":
                        tableGA.setEventLabel(dimensions.get(i));

                        break;
                    case "ga:date":
                        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                        Date convertedCurrentDate = null;
                        String year = dimensions.get(i).substring(0, 4);
                        String month = dimensions.get(i).substring(4, 6);
                        String day = dimensions.get(i).substring(6, 8);
                        String date = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
                        try {
                            convertedCurrentDate = simpleDateFormat.parse(date);
                        } catch (ParseException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        tableGA.setActualDate(convertedCurrentDate);

                        break;
                    case "ga:pageTitle":
                        tableGA.setPageTitle(dimensions.get(i));

                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < metrics.size(); j++) {
                DateRangeValues values = metrics.get(j);
                for (int k = 0; k < values.getValues().size() && k < metricHeaders.size(); k++) {
                    switch (metricHeaders.get(k).getName()) {
                    case "ga:timeOnPage":
                        tableGA.setTimeOnPage(Double.parseDouble(values.getValues().get(k)));
                        break;
                    case "ga:totalEvents":
                        tableGA.setTotalEvents(Integer.parseInt(values.getValues().get(k)));
                        break;
                    case "ga:avgSessionDuration":
                        tableGA.setAvgSessionDuration(Double.parseDouble(values.getValues().get(k)));

                        break;
                    case "ga:hits":
                        tableGA.setHits(Integer.parseInt(values.getValues().get(k)));

                        break;
                    }
                }

            }
            gaService.save(tableGA);
            System.out.println(tableGA.getPage());
            gaService.save(acessos);
        }
    }
}
```